# How to clear out NSUserDefaults on an updated app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, hockeyapp

I am using HockeyApp and Ship.io to deploy my ios app to multiple testers on every build. In my latest build, I changed the data types of some objects i was saving into NSUserDefaults, and now it crashes because old data stored on everyones local device clashes with this change. This crash disappears when a person deletes the app and reinstalls from scratch (bc userdefaults get cleared)

I want some kind of clearing logic so that NSUserDefaults get cleared out when people update to latest version. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check if an old key exists and if it does reset the defaults using:

```
NSString *domainName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:domainName];
```

(Typed on mobile so sorry if the formatting sucks)

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
-(void)removeNSUserDefaults {


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@“yourkey1”];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@“yourkey2”];
    //do this for all your keys..
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

just remove the objects from the dictionary

Comment: But i dont want to delete everytime user launches the app. If i do this, i only want to do it once someone updates app to latest version. Any ideas on logic i should use?? Maybe make a whole new boolean key to track if someones ever migrated to new app?

Comment: yes, a boolean key for "first launch" would be one way of doing this